# How to target only the last item in a v-for array?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have an array of objects inside v-for to create a component for each item like so:

```
<div v-for="(expense, idx) in myExpenses" :key="idx">
  <expense-panel
     v-model.number="expense.expensesValue"
     :expense="expense"
     :myExpenses="myExpenses"
     :showEdit="showEdit">
   </expense-panel>
</div>
```

I have a method to add and extra "expense" to the array:

*(I logged the item I am trying to specifically target)*

```
 addExpense() {
      this.myExpenses.push({
        expensesKey: "",
        expensesValue: null,
        subExpense: null,
      });
//The last item in the array
      console.log(this.myExpenses[this.myExpenses.length - 1]);
    },
```

**Is there a way in Vue to specifically add an input element to the last item of the array?**

I have a showInput = false in the parent's Data() already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add a `slot` to `expense-panel` and conditionally render `your-input` there only if it's the last item that is being rendered, like this:

```
<div v-for="(expense, idx) in myExpenses" :key="idx">
  <expense-panel
     v-model.number="expense.expensesValue"
     :expense="expense"
     :myExpenses="myExpenses"
     :showEdit="showEdit">
     <your-input v-if="idx === myExpenses.length - 1" />
   </expense-panel>
</div>
```

Other alternative could be passing a prop to the panel (like `is-last`) and baking the input into the `expense-panel`.

Also, if the input should be rendered visually AFTER the last item, you can simply add input after the whole list:

```
<div v-for="(expense, idx) in myExpenses" :key="idx">
  <expense-panel
     v-model.number="expense.expensesValue"
     :expense="expense"
     :myExpenses="myExpenses"
     :showEdit="showEdit">
   </expense-panel>
</div>
<your-input />
```

Comment: Such a fast response! I used your first option and it worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: How did I miss slots? smh

Comment: Sometimes you are lucky and the person who has your answer is browsing the questions at that very moment :D

Comment: Can I ping you for another question?

Comment: Sure ask, you can ask here in the comment I think !

Comment: I started to build this application without knowing the reason to learn Vuex. Now that I am almost done, I see the use of it because I have ALOT of conditional and states within the app.  I was wondering if I should create a store and clean it up or not worry about? By the way I am looking to show employers the project

Comment: Conditionals and states are very much fine within the app. The point when your app should switch to vuex is when you are starting to have more and more components that need access to the same state, but at the same time are in completely different part of the component tree (not parent - child relationship, but more sibling - sibling relationship). That's when state without vuex or similar solution starts becoming really ugly and hard to maintain.

Comment: Ok thats good to know. Appreciate all the help again.

Comment: Hey ajobi, I have a Vue.js code test this week and been trying to find mock test to work with.  Unfortunately, Vue.js doesn't have the amount of material as React.  I was wondering how I should prepeare and if there are anything that I should really focus on?

Comment: Start here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ - go over all the material and play with different pieces of code - I would say it's important you get a hands-on coding experience with all important concepts (this guide covers them all) ;-) This site is a very good source of info too for the future: https://www.vuemastery.com/ Good luck on the test man! ;-)

Comment: Appreciate it. I'm trying to grind it out.